# Append hidden ID to dynamically created DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using plain JavaScript and have created a number of dynamically generated DIVs for which I'm trying to append a unique ID to each with the idea of being able to update the ID of any selected DIV separately depending on an event being triggered. Is there a way to add a hidden (not visible on the page) editable ID or value pair to each DIV on generation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting to use a for loop to generate the divs, and the var = `document.createElement("DIV")`, then `var.setAttribute("id", i)` that will give unique ids.All in for loops.It should help.